# Have QGIS supported to return json as a web service?

Tags: gis, qgis

I am a newbie. I'm researching about QGIS to create a webgis. I don't know that have QGIS supported about returning data as a web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QGIS Server](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/index.html#label-qgisserver) is an implementation of various OGC web service standards that you can use. However, I think you're better off considering PostGIS and GeoServer.

Comment: have any open source for java web?